# MySQL cache, do not flush on update until 10 minutes old

Tags: php, mysql, caching

Is it possible to make it so that MySQL does not flush the cache when the table updates and holds that cache for at least 10 minutes before cache is flushed?

Basically, I'm caching a query that analyzes about 200k+ records and returns 10 rows of data. The query takes about 1.5 - 3 seconds. I'm using SQL_CACHE to cache that query, which after the first time takes 0.007(+-) seconds. The table updates very often (multiple times in less than a minute). So I want to make MySQL hold the cache for at least 10 minutes before it flushes that cached query to recalculate.

By the way, the query data is unique to each user on the site.

I'm using the Codeigniter framework, I know they have a built-in query caching feature however it's file-system based. Which is why I prefer MySQL's caching feature...

Thanks for all help guys!

Answer (score 0):

Three things cause things to be removed from the MySQL cache:

1. Not enough space
2. The data behind the query changed
3. The MySQL process restarts

You've got a fair bit of control over #1, because you can change the cache size. However, other queries can still take up cache space. I don't know how important controlling #2 is. You might want to use `SELECT SQL_NO_CACHE` to prevent those from entering the cache.

From the sounds of things, MySQL doesn't give you what you need to cache things the way you want to.

Have you considered optimizing the query? On that note, could you post the actual query?

Comment: I don't want to prevent data from entering the cache. I just want to prevent the cache from being flushed as soon as the table updates. The table basically holds traffic data, so records are added/updated frequently. I just need MySQL to hold the cached data for at least 10 minutes or so before it is invalidated.

My query is like:
`SELECT SQL_CACHE dday, COUNT(*) AS num, SUM(hits) AS sum_hits FROM table1 WHERE user_id =  '1' AND dmonth =  '11' AND dyear =  '2012' GROUP BY dday`

Comment: That's actually a pretty simple query. Have you tried adding user_id to the table index?

Comment: All required indexes are already added. I'm thinking the best alternative for this would be to just write a new db cache driver to handle the cached data using memcached..

Comment: "All required indexes are already added." Do you mean that you've tried adding user_id to the index, and it didn't help? Or do you mean that you didn't because MySQL didn't explicitly require it?

Comment: It's already added, and makes a good difference. I can easily improve the performance with the query by hardware, right now the hardware is at just a single core and 2gb ram (test server). I just wanted a way to cache it because later the records will grow into millions once put into production.